# How to use NotifyIcon

Tags: vb.net

I have been working on Something for a bit now, and I was wondering how to use the NotifyIcon in Visual Basic. I already know the code here it is:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
    NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
    NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(0)
End Sub
```

But I don't get a Notification/Balloon to show up. Can someone help?

Comment: [How to use the Windows Forms NotifyIcon component in Visual Basic .NET to display an icon for an application in the notification area](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/903898/how-to-use-the-windows-forms-notifyicon-component-in-visual-basic-net)

Comment: ShowBalloonTip(0) will show the tip for 0 milliseconds right?

Comment: @JacobH  Visual Studio just says: "Displays a balloon tip for a specified period of time"

Comment: Yes... and you have specified 0 as the amount of time... if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Also I am pretty sure you need to set the icon before you can show the tooltip (see the instructions linked above).

Comment: @JacobH Thanks. All that it needed was the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out.
I now know that I need to use a Icon in order for a message "bubble" to appear. Thanks to all those who helped!

Comment: It is not an answer. I think it should be deleted.

Comment: +1, assuming that you have already filled out the `NotifyIcon` 's `Text`, `BalloonTipText`, `BalloonTipTitle`, and `BalloonTipIcon` in the Designer.

Answer (score 0):

First Import using System.IO;
then copy paste this code in a button

notifyIcon1.Icon = new ("warning-icon.ico"));
notifyIcon1.Text = ""; :notifyIcon1.Visible = true;

```
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Welcome to ";
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Notify you for the use of this Software!!!";
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
```

Comment: `First Import using System.IO`.  Why?

Comment: because, after importing you will able to use the notify icon dlls

Comment: System.IO is for file and directory functions.  It has nothing to do with notify icons.